# Raster to Point conversion: how to convert every single pixel? on Google Earth Engine

Tags: gis, polygon, raster, points, google-earth-engine

Good day. I am trying to convert a raster to points using Google Earth Engine. My raster has one band (clusters) and it has been clipped to my ROI. I am aware of the `reduceToVectors` function on Google Earth Engine, but as I understand, this function creates areas with the **same adjacent value**, whereas what I want is to create **as many points as there are pixels**.

So far, I have tried different versions of:

```
var vectors = image.reduceToVectors({
  reducer : null,
  geometry : treat,
  scale:30,
  crs :image.projection().getInfo().crs,
  geometryType : 'centroid',
  labelProperty : 'null',
  eightConnected: false,
  maxPixels: 1e15
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ee.Image.sample`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.sample) returns a point for every pixel.

```
var vectors = image.sample({
  region: treat,
  geometries: true,  // if you want points
});
```

If you do not specify a `scale` and `crs`, it will use each pixel in the input image's original resolution. If you do, it will sample at the given scale instead.

Demonstration script:

```
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-110.00683426856995, 40.00274575078824],
    [-110.00683426856995, 39.99948706365032],
    [-109.99576210975647, 39.99948706365032],
    [-109.99576210975647, 40.00274575078824]]], null, false);
var image = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');
Map.setCenter(-110, 40, 16);
Map.addLayer(image, {min: 1000, max: 2000}, 'SRTM');

var vectors = image.sample({
  region: region,
  geometries: true,
});
print(vectors);
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection([region]).style({"color": "white"}));
Map.addLayer(vectors);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/625a710d6d315bad1c2438c73bde843b